# Draw with realX, realY, etc using Interp

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a problem with using the interp to improve my drawing function. For some reason the realX returns undefined every 3 frames. I'm using [this guide](https://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2015/01/detailed-explanation-javascript-game-loops-and-timing) to implement this functionality. The end goal is to make the collision system work so it would reflect bullets on an incomming shield (basicly how the bullets currently interact with the canvas borders. This is part of the code:

```js
//INT
var canvas = document.getElementById('ctx'),
    cw = canvas.width,
    ch = canvas.height,
    cx = null,
    bX = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    bY = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    mX,
    mY,
    lastFrameTimeMs = 0,
    maxFPS = 60,
    fps = 60,
    timestep       =    1000/fps,
    lastTime       =    (new Date()).getTime(),
    currentTime = 0,
    delta = 0,
    framesThisSecond = 0,
    lastFpsUpdate = 0,
    running = false,
    started = false,
    frameID = 0;

var gametimeStart = Date.now(),
    frameCount = 0,
    score = 0,
    player,
    enemyList = {},
    boostList = {},
    bulletList = {},
    pulseList = {},
    shieldList = {};

//CREATE , create object
var Unit = function(){
  this.x;
  this.y;
  this.realX;
  this.realY;
  this.type = "unit";
  this.hp = 0;
  this.color;
  this.collision = function(arc){
    return this.x + this.r + arc.r > arc.x 
    && this.x < arc.x + this.r + arc.r
    && this.y + this.r + arc.r > arc.y 
    && this.y < arc.y + this.r + arc.r
  };
  this.position = function(delta){
    boundX = document.getElementById('ctx').getBoundingClientRect().left;
    boundY = document.getElementById('ctx').getBoundingClientRect().top;
    this.realX = this.x;
    this.realX = this.y;
    this.realR = this.r;
    this.x += this.spdX * delta / 1000;
    this.y += this.spdY * delta / 1000;
    if (this.x < this.r || this.x + this.r > cw){
      this.spdX = -this.spdX;
      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        this.spdY += 100;
      } else {
        this.spdY -= 100;
      }
    }
    if (this.y < this.r || this.y + this.r > ch){
      this.spdY = -this.spdY;
      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        this.spdX += 100;
      } else {
        this.spdX -= 100;
      }
    }
  };
  this.draw = function(interp){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    //THIS DOESN'T WORK, the code is working perfectly without it
    this.x = (this.realX + (this.x - this.realX) * interp);
    this.y = (this.realY + (this.y - this.realY) * interp);
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  };
}
//Player
var Player = function(){
  //Coördinates
  this.x = 50;
  this.y = 50;
  this.r = 10;
  //Stats
  this.spdX = 30;
  this.spdY = 5;
  this.atkSpd = 1;
  this.hp = 100;
  //Other
  this.name;
  this.color = "green";
  this.type = "player";
  this.angle = 1;
  this.attack = function attack(enemy){
    enemy.hp -= 10;
  };
};
Player.prototype = new Unit();
//Boost
var Boost = function(){
  //Coördinates
  this.x = 300;
  this.y = 300;
  this.r = 5;
};
Boost.prototype = new Unit();
//Bullet
var Bullet = function(){
  //Coördinates
  this.x = player.x;
  this.y = player.y;
  this.r = 3;
  //Stats
  var angle = player.angle*90;
  this.spdX = Math.cos(angle/180*Math.PI)*200;
  this.spdY = Math.sin(angle/180*Math.PI)*200;
  //Other
  if (player.angle === 4)
    player.angle = 0;
  player.angle++;
};
Bullet.prototype = new Unit();

var player = new Player();
var boost = new Boost();
var bullet = new Bullet();

//UPDATE
update = function(delta){
  bullet.position(delta);
  if(player.collision(boost)){
    alert("collide");
  }
};
//DRAW
draw = function(interp){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  fpsDisplay.textContent = Math.round(fps) + ' FPS';
  boost.draw(interp);
  bullet.draw(interp);
  player.draw(interp);
};
//LOAD 
if (!document.hidden) { console.log("viewed"); }
function panic() { delta = 0; }
function begin() {}
function end(fps) {
  if (fps < 25) {
    fpsDisplay.style.color = "red";
  }
  else if (fps > 30) {
    fpsDisplay.style.color = "black";
  }
}
function stop() {
  running = false;
  started = false;
  cancelAnimationFrame(frameID);
}
function start() {
  if (!started) {
    started = true;
    frameID = requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
      draw(1);
      running = true;
      lastFrameTimeMs = timestamp;
      lastFpsUpdate = timestamp;
      framesThisSecond = 0;
      frameID = requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    });
  }
}
function mainLoop(timestamp) {  
  if (timestamp < lastFrameTimeMs + (1000 / maxFPS)) {
    frameID = requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    return;
  }
  delta += timestamp - lastFrameTimeMs;
  lastFrameTimeMs = timestamp;
  begin(timestamp, delta);
  if (timestamp > lastFpsUpdate + 1000) {
    fps = 0.25 * framesThisSecond + 0.75 * fps;
    lastFpsUpdate = timestamp;
    framesThisSecond = 0;
  }
  framesThisSecond++;
  var numUpdateSteps = 0;
  while (delta >= timestep) {
    update(timestep);
    delta -= timestep;
    if (++numUpdateSteps >= 240) {
      panic();
      break;
    }
  }
  draw(delta / timestep);
  end(fps);
  frameID = requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
start();
if (typeof (canvas.getContext) !== undefined) {
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '30px Arial';
}

//CONTROLLES
//Mouse Movement
document.onmousemove = function(mouse){
  var mouseX = mouse.clientX - bX;
  var mouseY = mouse.clientY - bY;

  if(mouseX < player.width/2)
    mouseX = player.width/2;
  if(mouseX > cw-player.width/2)
    mouseX = cw-player.width/2;
  if(mouseY < player.height/2)
    mouseY = player.height/2;
  if(mouseY > ch-player.height/2)
    mouseY = ch-player.height/2;

  player.x = mX = mouseX;
  player.y = mY = mouseY;
}
//Pauze Game
var pauze = function(){
  if(window.event.target.id === "pauze"){
    stop();
  }
  if(window.event.target.id === "ctx"){
    start();
  }
};
document.addEventListener("click", pauze);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}
main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 64px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<div id="fpsDisplay" style="font-size:50px; position:relative; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
<p id="status"></p>
<button id="pauze">Pauze</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Declare, define, use.

The problem is you are using a variables that are undefined.

You have 3 objects, Player, Boost, and Bullet each of which you assign the object Unit to their prototypes.

You declare and define unit

```
function Unit(){
    this.x;
    this.y;
    this.realX;
    this.realY;
    // blah blah

    this.draw = function(){
         // blah blah

    this.draw = function (interp) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        // this.realX and this.realY are undefined
        this.x = (this.realX + (this.x - this.realX) * interp);
        this.y = (this.realY + (this.y - this.realY) * interp);
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    };

}
```

Then Player

```
var Player = function () {
    //Coördinates
    this.x = 50;
    this.y = 50;
    this.r = 10;
    //Stats
    // etc....
};
```

Then add a Unit to the prototype.

```
Player.prototype = new Unit();
```

This gives Player the unit properties `x`, `y`, `realX`, `realY` **But** `realX` and `realY` are undefined. Same with the two other objects Boost, Bullet

Any existing properties with the same name stay as is and keep their values. Any properties not in Player will get them from Unit, but in unit you have only declared the properties `realX`, `realY` you have not defined them.

You need to define the properties by giving them a value before you use them. You can do this in Unit

```
function Unit(){
    this.x = 0; // default value I am guessing
    this.y = 0;
    this.realX = 10;
    this.realY = 10;
```

Then in Player

```
function Player(){
    this.x = 50; // these will keep the value they have
    this.y = 50;
    // realX and realY will have the defaults when you add to the prototype
    // Or you can define them here
    this.realX = 20;
    this.realY = 20;
```

Before you can use a variable you must define what it is or check if it is defined and take the appropriate action.

```
   // in draw function.
   if(this.realX === undefined){
       this.realX = 100; // set the default if not defined;
   }
```

BTW you should get rid of the alerts they are very annoying when you have them appear one after the other without a chance to navigate away from the page.

Comment: This seem to work. However the bullet start to to act strangely now:
https://jsfiddle.net/L37k388m/3/